# Reading user settings from another application

Tags: c#, console-application, windows

I have a windows application that writes user settings using the method described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx

These settings are saved to a file in the users directory e.g:

```
 c:\users\{you name}\Local\{Company}\{product}\user.config
```

I need to access these settings in a companion console application. Is this possible, at the moment the settings return null when I try to access them from the console application.

The code itself will look something like this:

To save the settings in App1:

```
namespace Application1{
    public class DemoSave{

      public void DoWork(){

         Application1.Properties.Settings.Default.CustomSettings.Title ="someValue";
         Application1.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

      }

    }
}
```

To read the settings in another app:

```
namespace Application2{
    public class Demo{

      public void DoWork(){

         var title = Application1.Properties.Settings.Default.CustomSettings.Title;

      }
    }
}
```

In Application2 the  Application1.Properties.Settings.Default.CustomSettings property is null.

Comment: Can you post your code, or at least enough of it to reproduce this issue? It's easier for everyone to help that way.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I did something similar, I had two projects in a solution (a windows service and a wpf application), and I had to reference the WPF app in the Win Service project to access it's settings (I assume you're talking about Namespace.Properties.Settings).  It seems to have worked fine for me.  In this case i had to set the access modifier on the settings to public though.  I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it worked for me for something very small and insignificant.

Comment: I have set this to public and I get the hard coded settings but not the user settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you even sure your pointing at the right place when you modifies/read the settings files.
Because that might be why it doesn't work.